Booting 24.04 in new Hp 15-fc0040p for new install
I have installed many times Ubuntu (older versions) in other computers and never had a problem. With this version of Ubuntu and in this PC Hp 15-fc0040p I can not boot the installation media using the F10 (boot from USB). The USB stick was made with
sudo dd if=/path_to/S/ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdg bs=4M status=progress && sync
-- It just freezes. Any help, please ?

It seems HP uses HP 15 for many models. What are your specs, CPU & video. Often new systems have additional settings in UEFI to restrict USB boot as that also is not secure. Check UEFI settings. Do you get grub menu and choice of live to test system. Some just have to try different installers, different flash drives & different ports.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb & https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  & https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-ubuntu-desktop/25312

Isn't that last part limited by the space? Perhaps it should be in quotes. I am not sure what the $$ sync would do in that situation. https://itsfoss.com/live-usb-with-dd-command/

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi all, it seems that producing the usb bootable pen with Ubuntu iso as user root and/or changing the USB port on the destination PC worked. I have never had this problem in older platforms, it is supposed to work in any USB port, right ?
